# How could i split this big string in to several strings in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js

How could I split this string into several strings in javascript?
i want the different strings for each part from '{' to '},'

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
{
   "result" : [
      {
         "DimmerLevels" : "none",
         "IsDimmer" : false,
         "Name" : "bathroom",
         "SubType" : "X10",
         "Type" : "Lighting 1",
         "idx" : "1"
      },
      {
         "DimmerLevels" : "none",
         "IsDimmer" : false,
         "Name" : "dining room",
         "SubType" : "X10",
         "Type" : "Lighting 1",
         "idx" : "5"
      },
      {
         "DimmerLevels" : "none",
         "IsDimmer" : false,
         "Name" : "hall",
         "SubType" : "X10",
         "Type" : "Lighting 1",
         "idx" : "3"
      },
      {
         "DimmerLevels" : "none",
         "IsDimmer" : false,
         "Name" : "kitchen",
         "SubType" : "X10",
         "Type" : "Lighting 1",
         "idx" : "2"
      },
      {
         "DimmerLevels" : "none",
         "IsDimmer" : false,
         "Name" : "parking",
         "SubType" : "X10",
         "Type" : "Lighting 1",
         "idx" : "4"
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK",
   "title" : "GetLightSwitches"
}
```

Comment: Well seeing as it looks like JSON, just parse it and access the data like normal

Comment: i want different strings for each part for example`{
         "DimmerLevels" : "none",
         "IsDimmer" : false,
         "Name" : "parking",
         "SubType" : "X10",
         "Type" : "Lighting 1",
         "idx" : "4"
      }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to split the string, but if it's valid JSON and you just want stringified JSON for each item in `result`, just parse the JSON, iterate through the items in `result`, and stringify them:

```
JSON.parse(string).result.map(item => JSON.stringify(item))
```

It would yield

```
[ '{"DimmerLevels":"none","IsDimmer":false,"Name":"bathroom","SubType":"X10","Type":"Lighting 1","idx":"1"}',
  '{"DimmerLevels":"none","IsDimmer":false,"Name":"dining room","SubType":"X10","Type":"Lighting 1","idx":"5"}',
  '{"DimmerLevels":"none","IsDimmer":false,"Name":"hall","SubType":"X10","Type":"Lighting 1","idx":"3"}',
  '{"DimmerLevels":"none","IsDimmer":false,"Name":"kitchen","SubType":"X10","Type":"Lighting 1","idx":"2"}',
  '{"DimmerLevels":"none","IsDimmer":false,"Name":"parking","SubType":"X10","Type":"Lighting 1","idx":"4"}' ]
```